# How to use io module and tornado.write at the same time

Tags: python, streaming, tornado, chunked, pydrive

There is a huge binary file uploaded to Google Drive. I am developing a tornado-based HTTP proxy server which provides a binary stream of the same huge file. It is natural to let the huge file to be proxied in multiple chunks (Download the contents using PyDrive, upload it with `self.write(chunk)` or something).

The problem is that there seems to be single choice : `googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseDownload`to download chunked binary files from Google Drive, but this library only supports FDs or `io.Base` objects as it's first argument.

https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseDownload-class.html

My code looks something like this:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
import io

class VideoContentHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,googledrive_id):
        googledrive_id = googledrive_id[1:]
        query = "'"+self.application.google_drive_folder_id+"' in parents and trashed=false"
        file_list = self.application.drive.ListFile({'q': query}).GetList()

        # io.FileIO will save the chunks to local file!
        # This is not what I want.
        # Using something different may solve the problem?
        with io.FileIO('/tmp/bigvid-from-pydrive.mp4', mode='wb') as local_file:
            for f in file_list:
                if f['id'] != googledrive_id: continue
                id = f.metadata.get('id')
                request = self.application.drive.auth.service.files().get_media(fileId=id)
                downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(local_file, request, chunksize=2048*1024)
                done = False

                while done is False:
                    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                    # Flush buffer and self.write(chunk)?

def main():
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.CommandLineAuth() # Already done
    self.drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    self.google_drive_folder_id = '<GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID>'

    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"^/videocontents(/.+)?$", handlers.api.VideoContentHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When should I call `self.write(chunk)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `io.BytesIO` instead of `io.FileIO` because it will be faster.

I haven't tested it, but this is how your code would look (read the comments for explanation):

```
from tornado import gen

# need make your get method a coroutine
@gen.coroutine
def get(self, googledrive_id):
    ...

    # with io.FileIO(...) <<<< YOU DON'T NEED THIS LINE NOW 
    for f in file_list:
        ...

        buffer = io.BytesIO() # create a BytesIO object

        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(buffer, request, chunksize=2048*1024)

        # Now is the time to set appropriate headers
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'video/mp4')
        # if you know the size of the video
        # write the Content-length header
        self.set_header('Content-Length', <size of file in bytes>)
        # if not, it's still ok

        done = False

        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

            # at this point, downloader has written 
            # the chunk to buffer
            # we'll read that data and write it to the response
            self.write(buffer.getvalue())

            # now fulsh the data to socket
            yield self.flush()

            # we'll also need to empty the buffer
            # otherwise, it will eat up all the RAM
            buffer.truncate(0)

            # seek to the beginning or else it will mess up
            buffer.seek(0)
```